# How to use update_post_meta() function properly?

Tags: post-meta

So I am working on a something like a plugin in my custom wordpress theme, and and in an options page I have a form whose action is the php file _options.php, in normal manner some data will be sent to this php file to edit meta data of some posts but this didn't work, So I really did a very basic job in the _options.php

I just added this line of code to the _options.php file

```
update_post_meta( 44, 'order_meta', 2);
```

So in theory whenever I open this php file in browser it should go to the post with ID 44 and edit the 'order_meta' metadata value to 2, or at least this is my understanding, but it doesn't work.

Also if I added another line of code after this line it doesn't execute, for example when I run this

```
update_post_meta( 44, 'order_meta', 2);
echo 'Testing text';
```

The "Testing text" is not echoed or anything, so I think this means that the above function is exiting the execution or something like that. I don't ave much background experience with php so you can consider me a beginner but I don't know why it doesn't work.

The Post with the id 44 is already present, and the meta with key order_meta already has a value of 1 but it doesn't seem want to change.

In short my question is how to edit a post meta data programmatically? Well my only guess is that I should somehow activate post editing when using this function which I don't know how to do, please if you know the answer please tell me.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1):

Directly accessing PHP files is not really how WordPress works.

You currently have your code in a random PHP file that has no connection to WordPress. It's probably throwing a Fatal error (Call to undefined function), which is why the next line doesn't get executed.

You said this code is in your theme, so I would start by putting that code in `functions.php`. If you want it in a different file, you'll need to add this to that `functions.php` file:

`require_once '_options.php';`

Or if it's in a folder in your theme (like "includes"), you'd do:

`require_once 'includes/_options.php';`

To control when that code is fired, you would use one of the many WordPress hooks.

For the correct way you create an options page, [check out this article in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages).